# How to make jinja2 templates variable by screen size using bootstrap on django?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jinja2, django-3.0

Django 3.0, jinja2 bootstrap 4

I have a table with 6 columns in it. This table looks great on a website, but it looks absolutely horrible on a phone. I use bootstrap for my row and column handling. I don't want the user to have to scroll left-right on a mobile device. So how do I do that with a jinja2 template? I'm open to how it'll turn out. My guess is that it'll look something like

Current output

```
Computer:
1,2,3,4,5,6
x,x,x,x,x,x
y,y,y,y,y,y
```

Desired output

```
col-sm-? device
1,2,3
x,x,x
x,x,x
y,y,y
y,y,y
```

Below is the code for the table

```
 <div class='container'>
        <table class="table document-list">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>File</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
                        <th>a</th>
                        <th>b</th>
                        <th>c</th>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class='document-body'>
                {% for instance in object_list %}
                        <tr class='contract-product'>
                            <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
                                <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                                <td>{{ instance.filename }}</td>
                                <td>{{ instance.description }}</td>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
                                <td><a href="{{ instance.get_download }}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
                                <td><a href="{{ instance.get_download }}?preview=True" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</a></td>
                                <td><a href="{{ instance.get_download }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Remove</a></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```